# Get the middle value of a class using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the third and forth value of `class="myDivs"` using jQuery?

Below is my code:

**HTML :**

```
 <div class="myDivs">Stack</div>
 <div class="myDivs">Over</div>
 <div class="myDivs">Flow</div>
 <div class="myDivs">And</div>
 <div class="myDivs">Exchange</div>
 <div class="myDivs">Question</div>
 <div class="myDivs">Ask</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to get the element at particular indexes.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/D5w3F/)**

```
$('.myDivs:eq(2), .myDivs:eq(3)').each(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

Using the combination of [:gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and [:lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) will give you range. It is useful when you have many elements.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/D5w3F/2/)**

```
$('.myDivs:gt(1):lt(2)').each(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

**Edit** To make it dynamic so that you do not have to hard code the middle you can divide the length of element collection and use it for start point, this will make it work independant of how many elements you have with class `myDivs`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/D5w3F/3/)**

```
mid = Math.floor($('.myDivs').length /2) -2;
$('.myDivs:gt(' + mid +'):lt(2)').each(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use **[.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)**

> Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of
>   indices

and push the text value into an array using **[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)**:

```
var valArr = $('.myDivs').slice(2,4).map(function() {
    return this.textContent;
}).get();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bE4fZ/1/)**

Answer (score 5):

One dynamic way is to calculate by the length of class count.

```
var mid1=Math.ceil($('.myDivs').length/2) - 1,
    mid2=Math.floor($('.myDivs').length/2) - 1;
if(mid1===mid2){
  //handle the case
}
$('.myDivs:eq('+mid1+'), .myDivs:eq('+mid2+')').each(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/D5w3F/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Reference them by index

```
var myDivs = $('.myDivs'),
    third = myDivs.eq(2),
    fourth = myDivs.eq(3);
```

To get the text value, just use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$( "div:nth-child(3)" ).html();
$( "div:nth-child(4)" ).html();
```

it will return you text of 3 and 4 div text
[Fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/nw59T/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a simple get function

http://api.jquery.com/eq/

```
var $myDivs = $(".myDivs");
var nr3 = $myDivs.eq(2);
var nr4 = $myDivs.eq(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to perform same operation on both the third and fourth divs, then use the following code:

```
$('.myDivs:eq(2), .myDivs:eq(3)').each(function(){
   // perform your operation here
});
```

If you want to perform different tasks on both of them, then

```
var myDivs = $(".myDivs"),
    thirdDiv = myDivs[2],
    fourthDiv = myDivs[3];
```

Now you can bind custom events to those particular divs alone.

for example :

```
$(thirdDiv).click(function() {
    // custom function
});
```

Comment: Oh ya! But it can be thirdDiv.onclick = function() { } :)